# How Local(shared) memory is actually allocated?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, opencl, nvidia, gpu-shared-memory

As an abstract concept of parallel computing, Local(shared) memory is allocated per Thread Blocks (CUDA) / Workgroups (OpenCL) and shared between all threads in the same Thread Blocks (CUDA) / Workgroups (OpenCL).

How it is actually allocated ? is it allocated by the first thread of the Block/Group or it is allocated before creating the Blocks by the memory controller ? or something else ?

Comment: @DarkZeros: That comment probably a sufficient answer, if you would care to add it as one

Comment: @DarkZeros Thank you , this explains it very good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OpenCL considers "Local Memory" is:

- Memory available only during the kernel execution, that is shared only by elements of the same workgroup. Each workgroup can only see their local memory.
- The memory usage is known at compile time and limited.

It is very similar to registers or L1/L2 cache in CPUs / multicore systems. Compilers know about the registers of the target CPU and plan accordingly.
When the scheduler schedules the workgroups to hardware resources will always ensure enough memory is in place for each workgroup.

**You can consider local memory inside kernel execution as a pointer to memory that is already allocated, similar to a register or private memory**.